# Ansible AnsibleUndefinedVariable no attribute

Tags: yaml, ansible

I have the following files vars/main.yml

```
testconfig:
 - {hostname: router123, example: no ip cef}

cisco_891_l2interfaces:
 - FastEthernet0
 - FastEthernet1
 - FastEthernet2
 - FastEthernet3
 - FastEthernet4
 - FastEthernet5
 - FastEthernet6
 - FastEthernet7

euvar:
 - {dc1: "1.1.1.1", dc2: "1.2.2.2"}
```

tasks main.yml

```
- name: Generate configuration files for DMVPN router
  template: src=router.j2 dest=/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/RTR-TEMPLATE/bla/bla.txt
  with_items: testconfig
```

router.j2

```
{{item.example}}

!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!

{{euvar.dc1}}
```

This gives me the error, I am unsure how to reference euvar.dc1 from router.j2

```
    TASK: [router | Generate configuration files for DMVPN router] ****************
fatal: [localhost] => {'msg': "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'list object' has no attribute 'dc1'", 'failed': True}
fatal: [localhost] => {'msg': 'One or more items failed.', 'failed': True, 'changed': False, 'results': [{'msg': "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'list object' has no attribute 'dc1'", 'failed': True}]}

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Comment: should `euvar` be looped over as well (like `testconfig`)? or do you just need to pick the value of the first row? (in the latter case, it's `{{euvar[0].dc1}}`)

Comment: Basically I have regional specific IP addresses.I want to get the value from dc1 euvar when region = EU and use usvar dc1 when region = us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined `euvar` as a list of dicts. But you're trying to access the first list item directly. From my feeling you just want a dict like so:

```
euvar: {dc1: "1.1.1.1", dc2: "1.2.2.2"}
```

Or for those who prefer readability:

```
euvar:
  dc1: 1.1.1.1
  dc2: 1.2.2.2
```

Then you will be able to access it as `{{ euvar.dc1 }}`.

In case you really meant to define a list of dicts, then you can access it like @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ already commented on the question: `{{ euvar[0].dc1 }}`

---

Please also have a look at Ansibles [inventory groups](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups) and [group_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data). The name of your variable suggests you're working around Ansibles [best practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#group-and-host-variables).

Comment: The links was corrupted!